# When did wings become an attribute to these creatures?

Tags: greek, mythical-creatures

Manticore- head of a human, body of a lion, tail of poisonous spines

Chimera- head of a lion and goat, snake/dragon as a tail, breaths fire

Yet, when images are drawn of these creatures, they have wings about half the time. They are usually described as bat wings.

```
The Chimera is also not depicted by Greeks with wings. I would suggest back up or editing a little bit the question.
```

If not by Greeks, then by who? How, or when, were they first described with wings?

Comment: Please back up your assertion that these creatures are "almost always" drawn with wings. Neither Wikipedia article has a description or image with wings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about “almost always”. But Dungeons & Dragons has probably contributed to popularizing this image. In D&D, both the manticore and chimera have wings.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manticore_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)

Comment: Yes. In d&d chimera is a mix of a dragon, a lion and a goat, so it has dragon wings. Traditional Greek chimera has no wings. But other mixed creatures from other mythologies do have wings and are refered to as chimera. (chimera is any mix of animals)